# How to place all objects in all cells at the same distance from the borders

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I'm trying to make a tool to optimize the process of creating new planograms, layouts. The file has many pictures, now I'm placing and resizing them equally one to another manually, but it still has some difference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hChgm.png

How can I place them in the right order with the right size (they should be placed in the middle of the cell with a small indent from below)?

Answer (score 1):

Tip 1: Dragging a shape whilst holding down the alt-key causes Excel to snap to the cell grid. 
Tip 2: control-click the shapes to select them all and then use Align, Top from the contextual ribbon tab. Then you can drag all of them to the right vertical location.

This macro will align all shapes the same as the one you have currently selected when you run it. It also updates the width and height of all of them. To use it: Position one picture the way you like it, including the size. Select that picture and then run the code. Make sure you save the file first in case you don't like the end result so you can close the file without saving and open the just saved copy.

```
Sub AlignAndSizeAllShapes()
    Dim dLeftOffset As Double
    Dim dTopOffset As Double
    Dim dHeight As Double
    Dim dWidth As Double
    Dim oShp As Shape
    dLeftOffset = Selection.Left - Selection.TopLeftCell.Left
    dTopOffset = Selection.Top - Selection.TopLeftCell.Top
    dHeight = Selection.Height
    dWidth = Selection.Width
    For Each oShp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        oShp.Left = oShp.TopLeftCell.Left + dLeftOffset
        oShp.Top = oShp.TopLeftCell.Top + dTopOffset
        oShp.Width = dWidth
        oShp.Height = dHeight
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I use it, but they still have some difference. It's killing tbh, I have more than 100 pictures to size and move like this. I was wondering if someone could possibly help me to make a macros or anything like this

Comment: I have added a small macro to size and align all shapes the same